# modify and apply limits.conf without reboot

Tags: linux, ulimit

I have added a line in `/etc/security/limits.conf` to increase the number of open files.

```
*    hard nofile 4096
root hard nofile 16384
```

However when I run `ulimit -n` it says 1024 which is the default value. I did a logout and login but still see 1024. How can I apply the change?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're using `bash`, `ulimit -n` will only display the soft limit.  To get the hard limit, you need to do `ulimit -Hn`.

On my system, I see this:

```
$ ulimit -n
1024
$ ulimit -Hn
4096
```

Answer (score 34):

Changes made by `ulimit` command will be applied immediately **without reboot** (for new processes)

```
$ ulimit -n 4096       # set soft limit
$ ulimit -Hn 16384     # set hard limit
```

Also [`prlimit`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/prlimit) command (from `util-linux` package on Debian) can be used to check (or modify) limit value (for current shell):

```
$ prlimit   
RESOURCE   DESCRIPTION                             SOFT      HARD UNITS
AS         address space limit                unlimited unlimited bytes
CORE       max core file size                         0 unlimited bytes
...
```

Limits can be configured per-process, you can check it using:

```
cat /proc/<PID>/limits    # where <PID> is replaced by actual process ID
prlimit -p 4562           # or using prlimit
```

For modifying the limit is syntax is following:

```
prlimit -p <PID> --<resource>=<soft>:<hard>
```

set maximum number of opened files for process `4561`:

```
prlimit --pid 4561 --nofile=128051:256102
```

In order to make such changes permanent, you have to modify `/etc/security/limits.conf` by adding your limits:

```
* soft nofile 4096
* hard nofile 16384
```

**However, wildcard `*` won't apply for `root` user.** In order to do so, you have to state it explicitly:

```
* soft nofile 4096
* hard nofile 16384
root soft nofile 4096
root hard nofile 16384
```

These limits will be applied **after creating a new session** (of course after reboot). Switch to another user using `su` or login via `ssh` and check the updated limits:

```
su - myuser
ulimit -Sa
ulimit -Ha
```

**NOTE**: Usually some service is running out of resources, be sure to check limits also on process level (having largest possible value for `root` user is not a solution). If value configured in `/etc/security/limits.conf` is too large (not supported on your kernel), the default value will be used instead.

On **systemd** systems there are `/etc/systemd/user.conf` (`/etc/systemd/user.conf.d/*.conf` for user-specific values) config where limits per user can be overriden:

```
[Manager]
DefaultLimitAS=4G:16G
DefaultLimitNOFILE=1048576
```

Also there `/etc/systemd/system.conf` for system-wide configuration.

Some older distributions had issues with applying limits immediately, where modifying `/etc/pam.d/common-session` or `/etc/pam.d/login` would help. This is usually not necessary:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

Make sure to check `/var/log/auth.log` first, when you're having issues with applying limits.

Comment: I had an issue with this approach which was really strange.
I am using Ubuntu 14 and enabled `pam_limits.so` in `/etc/pam.d/common-session`. I have configured in `/etc/security/limits.conf` user x to have hard and soft limits for `nofile` 64000. `sudo -u x` then `ulimit -a` shows me that the changes were not applied. I realized that `su` and `sudo` have different pam configurations so in order to make it work properly I needed to enable the `pam_limits.so` in `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive`.
If you are wondering what is the use case - I use ansible and sudo to change user.

Comment: For some reason, I had to add it to `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` for it to work.

Comment: Excellent answer!